# Equator D5 Studio Monitors. Thoughts? 

Tags: studio-monitors, post-production, stereo-imaging

[link text](http://www.equatoraudio.com/D5_Studio_Monitors_with_DSP_300_Pair_p/d5.htm)

Does anyone have experience with these monitors? The coaxial design looks very appealing for creating phase coherent stereo imaging. I know they've been given rave reviews over at gearslutz, just wondering what you guys and gals think as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have a client who records at her house and comes into the studio to tweak and mix.  She had some monitors that were far less than serious, not worth mentioning a name.  I recommended she look into some decent monitors. She got entered into a giveaway drawing as a promotion for these monitors and won.  The next time I visited her studio we worked extensively with these monitors and I was awed when she told me they were $300/pr. And these she won!

I ordered a pair the next day. I'd say that out of all the monitors I've owned over the years (many) these are the best value bar none.  I would expect to pay nearly twice the price for this quality.

I've been a stickler for good clear full midrange and tight imaging. After using these for the past few months I've learned that I can trust them without much cross-referencing.

I should get another pair though as I keep taking these out of the studio and into the living room to listen to my favorite movies and shows. My living room is a larger room so I added a small subwoofer and the system delivers a roomful of ear candy. Sterling!

No reservations!

Answer (score 0):

I have a pair of D5s and I absolutely love them. Although they are my first pair that I own, I have used a few others in other studios including Genelecs and Mackies. The Equators are small but really loud. The coaxial design does help in the imaging. Mixes translate well and details are there.

It is a little light on the extreme low end but its usable without a sub. I do mainly music so I don't always need to have the sub bass. For the low price, it will be extremely hard to find anything to beat it in this price range. Its not flattering and perfect for mixing.

There's really nothing to complain about it except it was a little difficult to source in Asia. They have a new website to ship to Asia but it is priced higher than US/UK/Europe.

Comment: yea, here in india its priced a bit higher, how did you get it in singapore?